# Why does mkdir does not work in dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have following lines in my dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04 AS setup_env
# ...

FROM setup_env AS clone_build_public_repos 
# ...
WORKDIR /my_prod/opencv 
RUN mkdir -p ./build
WORKDIR /my_prod/opencv/build
RUN cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE  &> cmake.log
RUN make -j4 &> make.log
RUN make install &> make-install.log
# ...

FROM clone_build_public_repos 
ENTRYPOINT ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

I run docker command as

```
docker build . --progress plain -t my_company:my_prod &> docker-build.log
```

The docker-build.log file contains following lines:

```
#28 [clone_build_public_repos 17/37] WORKDIR /my_prod/opencv
#28 CACHED

#29 [clone_build_public_repos 18/37] RUN mkdir -p ./build
#29 DONE 0.3s

#30 [clone_build_public_repos 19/37] WORKDIR /my_prod/opencv/build
#30 DONE 0.0s

#31 [clone_build_public_repos 20/37] RUN cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$(python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.prefix)") -D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=$(which python3) -D PYTHON_DEFAULT_EXECUTABLE=$(which python3) -D WITH_GTK=ON -D WITH_FFMPEG=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib/modules -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D HAVE_opencv_python3=ON .. &> cmake.log
#31 DONE 0.4s

#32 [clone_build_public_repos 21/37] RUN make -j4 &> make.log
#32 DONE 0.3s

#33 [clone_build_public_repos 22/37] RUN make install &> make-install.log
#33 DONE 0.4s
```

However, when I checked vscode container browser, it does not contain any `build` folder:

[image]

What I am missing here?

Comment: Show your `docker run` command (or compose file). I bet it's due to a volume mapping.

Comment: Its: `docker run -d -v $(pwd):/my_prod --name my_prod_container my_company:my_prod`. Is `-v $(pwd):/my_prod` a culprit? My `$(pwd)` does indeed have `opencv` directory without `build`. `opencv` should not be there at all, though. I am cloning private repos in `$(pwd)` and want to mount them inside same directory `my_prod` so that those private repos can refer `/my_prod/opencv` that is clone and built inside dockerfile.

Comment: Running `mkdir` _in the container_ creates a directory _in the container_, not on your host... when you don't have a bind mount. When you use `-v`, that means you're using the directory from your host at runtime; but that's runtime behavior only; it doesn't change build time.

Comment: So you have the `build/` directory there _at build time_, but at runtime using `-v` means you're overriding with the directory from your host that doesn't have it. The mkdir itself works perfectly well.

Answer (score 0):

Your bind mount *obscures* the contents of the directory in the image. I.e. your host directory replaces `/my_prod` and everything in it in the container.

From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#mount-into-a-non-empty-directory-on-the-container):

> If you bind-mount a directory into a non-empty directory on the
> container, the directory's existing contents are obscured by the bind
> mount. This can be beneficial, such as when you want to test a new
> version of your application without building a new image. However, it
> can also be surprising and this behavior differs from that of docker
> volumes.

If you run the container without the bind mount like this, you should be able to see the `build` directory:

```
docker run -d --name my_prod_container my_company:my_prod
```